# Pool stats showing abnormally high H/s

Tags: mining-pools, hashrate, api

The pool I am using (mineXMR.com) regularly shows a hash rate of 250-300+ H/s for my computer despite the miner I am using (XMR-Stak-CPU) showing hash rates that do not exceed ~190 H/s. What could be the cause of this discrepancy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for this:

- your are being consistently lucky and finding more shares that you'd expect
- you have another computer mining to the same address, which you forgot
- you're mining to a public address (eg, an exchange), and someone else is also mining to that address
- the pool's buggy

As Steve Pazitka said, the pool can only infer your hash rate by looking at the timing and difficulty of the shares you submit, so reported hash rate typically varies with a long term average being at your actual hash rate, or maybe a bit lower due to network overheads.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying "Hash rate" is average value of submitted hashes, miner hash rate is actual value of all hashes.