# Pool live tracker showing different hash rate than the miner log

Tags: hashrate, hashrate-comparison

When I look at the pool live tracker, my worker shows about 160H/s currently and about 190 for 1h average. But my miner software is showing the following in the logs:

```
[timestamp] accepted: 443/443 (diff 0.000), 232.56 H/s yes!
[timestamp] CPU #3: 58.64 H/s
[timestamp] accepted: 444/444 (diff 0.000), 232.66 H/s yes!
[timestamp] CPU #2: 59.25 H/s
[timestamp] CPU #0: 56.87 H/s
[timestamp] CPU #1: 58.47 H/s
```

Why does the hashrate differ so much? Is the pool cheating, or calculating the hashrate in a different way? I see there is [a question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3692/pool-stats-showing-abnormally-high-h-s) about higher hashrate reported by the pool, but mine is showing way less. Is about 30% difference normal?

The logs are from the cpu miner, but the same happens on the gpu miner too. The pool reports way less for the hashrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your miner reports and what the effective hash rate your pool receives are often different. I'd say 10-30% lower than what your machine reports sounds about right, actually.

This is mostly because not every hash your machine produces is accepted by the pool, and so you have a certain threshold of shares that don't get submitted or accepted. The hash rate you see on your pool is an approximate guess at your hash rate based on the number of accepted shares you receive over time.

However, if you did want to test to see if you aren't getting messed around by your pool, try connecting to a different one for a couple of hours and compare results. Also be aware that it is possible that your mining software reports hash rates which are higher than they actually are. Some software providers have been known to do this to give the appearance that their mining software is better somehow.

Comment: I found this question from the related questions list that actually describes the same thing that you did, but in a bit different words: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/how-to-achieve-uniform-hash-rate